# IS DNS speed important for a server?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I want to ask if choosing the DNS server selection is important for server speed.

For example: I have small office server connected to ISP internet. I have a modem connected to server, so public IP and DNS servers from ISP are loaded directly to server.

If a client visits the site his set up DNS will resolve my IP and he will be connected to my server, which will serve the static files.

Will my server need look up to DNS for delivering that static file to him?

My understanding of DNS are that its some type of "library" of IP addresses for domain names. Choosing faster DNS server can resolve to faster loading of files for client.

But can setting fastest DNS on my server lead to faster loading of my site for client?

Comment: it will be important, but DNS is usually using a cache, you usually have a name service cache on the clients, caching the entries, making the queries faster the second time they run a query. with long TTLs and caching, DNS server performance or network performance are not "heavily" impacting imho.

Answer (score 1):

A DNS query for your domain name is done by the client before they connect to the server. Your server does not need to do a DNS query to respond to a client request.

If you make outgoing requests from your server by domain name you will need to do DNS requests. This could happen if you call microservices, and for standard things like Windows updates.

DNS speed is a factor in website performance, but it's not typically the most important factor. You can use Route53 / CloudFlare / any other DNS provider that has distributed DNS servers, which should give the client 5 - 30ms DNS lookup times. This is cached so it's only looked up once, but any resources on the page (fonts, graphics, analytics, etc) is its own DNS query. This can add up if the DNS servers are slow, but you typically have no control over the DNS for your dependant resources.

If you're serving a static website it's typically going to be a lot cheaper to use a hosted service than running your own server. AWS S3 + CloudFront might cost you a couple of dollars per month, but the setup and configuration can take a lot of time on AWS as it's a complex enterprise environment.